# In the 2005-2006 NBA season why was Denver seeded above Dallas despite having 16 fewer wins?

Tags: basketball, ranking

In the 2005-2006 nba why was denver seeded above dallas even though they had 16 fewer wins? this never made sense to me?

Answer (score 3):

In the Western conference, the Denver Nuggets won the Northwest division. Division winners (Spurs in Southwest, Suns in Pacific, and Nuggets in Northwest) get the highest seeds based on record (1 - Spurs, 2 - Suns, then 3 - Nuggets).

Then, non-division winners are seeded based on record. The Dallas Mavericks finished second in the Southwest division and had the best record of a non-division winner, thus awarding them the fourth seed (followed by 5 - Grizzlies, 6 - Clippers, 7 - Lakers, and 8 - Kings). You will also notice that the 8th seeded Sacramento Kings had the same record as the 3rd seeded Denver Nuggets.

Source: [(1)](http://www.nba.com/standings/2005/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Div.html) [(2)](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2006.html)

The following verbiage from [NBA.com](http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html) will also help in regards to understanding seeding:

> Teams 1 to 4 in each conference are the three division winners and the
>   team with the next best regular-season record, with the seeding of
>   these four teams determined by regular-season record. The playoffs
>   seedings of Teams 5 to 8 are based upon regular-season record.

NOTE: I believe the verbiage above was put into place after the 2005-2006 season.